# dataframe index existence checking

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I execute the following code, it generates the horizontal line (as desired), but only when this location (index position available) is present in my_data (my_data filtered/chosen previously).

```
plt.axhline(y=my_data.loc[6805], color='green', linestyle='dashed')
```

I would like to write something like:

```
If my_data.loc[6805] is not None:
   plt.axhline(y=my_data.loc[6805], color='green', linestyle='dashed')
```

How can I check if the index position is available or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1] Error Exception Handling

- You can achieve this using error exception handling
- If that location does not exist then you will get a `KeyError:`
- try-except is what you are looking for

  ```
  try:
      mplt.axhline(y=my_data.loc[6805], color='green', linestyle='dashed')
  except:
      pass
  ```

2] Check if 6805 is the index **[this is only if 6805 is the index]**

- Other thing you can do is check in 6805 exist as the index

  ```
  if 6805 in my_data.index.tolist():
      mplt.axhline(y=my_data.loc[6805], color='green', linestyle='dashed')
  ```

3] Check the number of rows

- You can check if the total number of rows is greater then or equal to  6805

  ```
  if my_data.shape[0] >= 6805 :
      mplt.axhline(y=my_data.loc[6805], color='green', linestyle='dashed')
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jai. For the solution [(1) worked immediately] and all other important info related. Regards, fskilnik.